# Has any research been done into navigability for offroad vehicles for different types of terrain and elevation changes?

Tags: cost-path, shortest-path, cost-surface, tobler

"Navigability" is a pretty broad category, so to be specific, what I mean is, given some GIS data, how can we calculate the cost of moving from point A to point B, in some context?

For example: A hiker weighing 70kg is traversing an upward slope of grade 15 degrees in dense terrain. What are the costs in terms of *time to traverse* the given segment with these parameters, and *calories burned* (as a measure of *effort*).

For the former, we have [Tobler's hiking function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobler%27s_hiking_function), as well as many others (for instance, [this](https://repository.lboro.ac.uk/articles/journal_contribution/Route_choice_in_hilly_terrain/9388442) fantastic article on the subject). Given such a function to estimate pace/speed, we can then use one of many functions to try and estimate a measure for navigability such as *calories burned* for a hiker.

Has similar research been done for *offroad vehicles* navigating difficult terrain? For instance, given some basic specs for an ATV (weight, max/average speed, average fuel consumption rate, max slope), are there formulas similar to Tobler's hiking function for estimating the speed that such a vehicle can comfortably take over a certain grade? What about an estimate of fuel consumption in such a scenario?

I'm surprised that after much searching, I was not able to find any research of this sort in the GIS community, despite the relatively large amount of research that has been done into navigability and cost models relating to off-road hiking cost models. Does anyone know if such research has been done, and if so, what a better way of finding such resources might be?

Comment: What scenario would you be interested in such information? People tend to drive along roads or tracks why would you want to know about driving a vehicle across a marshland for example? I would imagine you wouldn't get more than a few metres? It seems to me the only people in this world who would be interested in driving across _anything_ would be military? Have you tried to search military research?